# multiple google +1 sharing buttons

Tags: google-plus, share, schema.org

I have a single webpage with multiple items.
And I want to be able to share them separately with a google+1  containing a # to automatically scroll to the correct one.

For each of the items I defined the schema and verified with the testing tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

This sees all the different items, I used the product schema.

But when I click the G+1 button it generates the same preview for each G+1 button.

Is it possible to have multiple G+1 buttons on a single page with different content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The share content is based on the URL and ignores the #fragment. If you want multiple share summaries you will have to have multiple URLs.